# How can i pass HTML inside React Hook Function and display inside my component secure?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html-parsing, sanitization

I have a custom react hook to display a popover when i hover over an nav item like this:

```js
<a 
  href={url} 
  onMouseEnter={(e) => showPopover(e.target)} 
  onMouseLeave={() => showPopover(false)}

> Hover me </a>
```

I want to pass the content to the hook and display inside my popover. If I only had text this would be pretty simple, however the popover can also contain JSX, like an icon component or HTML tags like `<div>` or `<p>`

So what is the best way to pass the content to my hook. Could it work like that?

```js
<a 
  href={url} 
  onMouseEnter={(e) => showPopover(e.target, "<div>This is a div</div>")} 
  onMouseLeave={() => showPopover(false)}

> Hover me </a>
```

I pass the HTML String to my hook and parse them via a library like `react-html-parser` However, I then have the problem that i also need sanitized my HTML. Would there also be a possibility to pass only the text and handle the styling somehow differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to transfer something that you should not, normally. If you want to display an HTML with CSS, then this should go into a **component**.

Pass into that component the argument that you need to choose whatever style/icon you want to display and render the component.

```js
if (shouldComponentARender){
    render(ComponentA)
}else if(shouldComponentBRender){
    render(ComponentB)
}
```

Here, you can easily pass only a string or flag. That would be better testable and extendable.